Can I fit a 27,5x2.40 tyre on a 584x25 rim?
So I bought a 27.5x2.40 new tyre for my dt swiss rim 584x25. My past tyre was a 27.5x2.50 and i though I could go 0.1 inch shorter will it fit or not really?
My ne tyre I ordered are some michelin wild enduro 27.5x2.40 (61,584)
Thx a lot

it's a fit. no problem.

Does this answer your question? What is the maximum tire or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle

Your real question here is "Can I reduce tyre width by 2.5mm?" and the answer is very likely yes.  Going bigger depends on frame clearances, but going slightly smaller is almost always okay.

Tyre sizing is confusing, and mixing systems like this leads to more confusion
584mm is an ETRTO measurement and it is an accurate system, whereas 27.5" is functionally the same.
Your measurement is in width, so 2.4" is 61mm and 2.5" is 63.5mm (rounded to either 63 or 64)
ETRTO of 61-584 is the same as 2.4" wide by 27.5"ETRTO of 63-584 is the same as 2.5" wide by 27.5"
More information is found at    What is the maximum tire or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle

OK yeah I just found what I was doing wrong everything is working now thx a lot
